# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am trying to insert some values into an Oracle Database 10g Express Edition retrieved through a form. Here is the code,

```
package com.cid_org.model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
//import java.util.Collection;
//import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class CrimeReportPOJO {

private Map<String,String[]> complaintFormData;
private Connection connection;
private int complaintID=0;

public CrimeReportPOJO(Map<String,String[]> complaintFormData,Connection connection){
    this.complaintFormData = complaintFormData;
    this.connection = connection;
    sendCrimeData();
}

private void sendCrimeData(){
    try{
        String query_VICTIM_DETAILS ="INSERT INTO VICTIM_DETAILS ("+
                                     "VICTIM_FIRST_NAME,"+
                                     "VICTIM_MIDDLE_NAME,"+
                                     "VICTIM_LAST_NAME,"+
                                     "VICTIM_UID_NO,"+
                                     "VICTIM_AGE,"+
                                     "VICTIM_GENDER,"+
                                     "VICTIM_ADDRESS,"+
                                     "NEAREST_POLICE_CHOWKI,"+
                                     "VICTIM_ZIP_CODE,"+
                                     "VICTIM_PHONE_NO,"+
                                     "VICTIM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,"+
                                     "COMPLAINT_ID)"+
                                     "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        String query_VICTIMIZER_DETAILS ="INSERT INTO VICTIM_DETAILS ("+
                                         "VICTIMIZER_BUSINESS_NAME,"+
                                         "VICTIMIZER_FIRST_NAME,"+
                                         "VICTIMIZER_MIDDLE_NAME,"+
                                         "VICTIMIZER_LAST_NAME,"+
                                         "VICTIMIZER_GENDER,"+
                                         "VICTIMIZER_ADDRESS,"+
                                         "VICTIMIZER_ZIP_CODE,"+
                                         "VICTIMIZER_PHONE_NO,"+
                                         "VICTIMIZER_EMAIL_ADDRESS,"+
                                         "COMPLAINT_ID)"+
                                         "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        String query_COMPLAINT_DESCRIPTION ="INSERT INTO COMPLAINT_DESCRIPTION ("+
                                            "COMPLAINT_ID,"+
                                            "COMPLAINT_DESC,"+
                                            "COMPLAINT_TIME_STAMP)"+
                                            "VALUES(?,?,?)";

        String query_COMPLAINT_COUNT_DETAILS ="INSERT INTO COMPLAINT_COUNT_DETAILS("+
                                              "VICTIM_UID_NO,"+
                                              "COMPLAINT_COUNT)"+
                                              "VALUES(?,?)";

        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query_VICTIM_DETAILS);

        /*Now, lets extract the data to be inserted from the map object
         * and call the setString() methods on those values */  

        /*Collection<String[]> c = complaintFormData.values();
        Iterator<String[]> it = c.iterator();
        int i=1;
        while(it.hasNext()){
            String[] s = it.next();
            ps.setObject(i, (Object)s[0] );
            i++;
        }*/

        String[] s= complaintFormData.get("personal_first_name");
        System.out.println(s[0]);
        System.out.println(s);
        ps.setString(1,s[0]);
        s= complaintFormData.get("personal_middle_name");
        ps.setString(2,s[0]);

        s= complaintFormData.get("personal_last_name");
        ps.setString(3,s[0]);

        s= complaintFormData.get("personal_aadhar_card_no");
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(s[0]));
        ps.setInt(4,Integer.parseInt(s[0]) );


        s= complaintFormData.get("personal_age");
        ps.setInt(5,Integer.parseInt(s[0]));

        s= complaintFormData.get("personal_gender");
        ps.setString(6,s[0]);

        s= complaintFormData.get("personal_address");
        ps.setString(7,s[0]);

        s= complaintFormData.get("police_chowki");
        ps.setString(8,s[0]);

        s= complaintFormData.get("personal_zip_code");
        ps.setInt(9,Integer.parseInt(s[0]));

        s= complaintFormData.get("personal_phone_no");
        ps.setInt(10,Integer.parseInt(s[0]));

        s= complaintFormData.get("personal_email_id");
        ps.setString(11,s[0] );
        System.out.println(s[0]);

        /*To insert complaint ID into the last column COMPLAINT_ID I am
         * calling getComplaintID() method which tells me whether its the 
         * first time I am inserting into the database or there are already 
         * complaints registered*/

        complaintID = getComplaintID();
        System.out.println(complaintID);
        if(complaintID==-2){
            //First time
            ps.setInt(12,1);
        }
        else{
            ps.setInt(12,++complaintID);
        }

        ps.executeUpdate(query_VICTIM_DETAILS);

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

private int getComplaintID(){

    String query = "SELECT MAX(COMPLAINT_ID)"+ 
                   "FROM COMPLAINT_DESCRIPTION";
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if(rs.next()){
            return rs.getInt(1);
        }
        else{ 
            /*-2 indicates that the table is empty and the first
            **complaint is being registered*/
            return -2;  
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    /*The syntax compels to return an integer value*/
    return -1;
}
}
```

The problem is that I am getting the following exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01008: not all variables bound
```

The stack trace is:

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:955)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1169)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1615)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1580)
at com.cid_org.model.CrimeReportPOJO.sendCrimeData(CrimeReportPOJO.java:130)
at com.cid_org.model.CrimeReportPOJO.<init>(CrimeReportPOJO.java:20)
at com.cid_org.controller.CrimeReportControllerServlet.doPost(CrimeReportControllerServlet.java:52)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Here is the VICTIM_DETAILS table:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1TEIK.png

and here is the COMPLAINT_DESCRIPTION table,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxvPN.png

What I have tried: I inserted the following statement

```
System.out.println(complaintID);
```

after calling the getComplaintID() method and the output that I got on the console matches what is actually already in the table(I have cross checked it) and this indicates that the code reaches there successfully which also indicates that getComplaintID() method successfully executed.

Also, I left no value as null in the form and all the values were constraint to the table format.

Comment: Did you try to print the query to console before executing the update to see how it's formed?

Comment: @boolean :Yeah I just did and I got this, INSERT INTO VICTIM_DETAILS (VICTIM_FIRST_NAME,VICTIM_MIDDLE_NAME,VICTIM_LAST_NAME,VICTIM_UID_NO,VICTIM_AGE,VICTIM_GENDER,VICTIM_ADDRESS,NEAREST_POLICE_CHOWKI,VICTIM_ZIP_CODE,VICTIM_PHONE_NO,VICTIM_EMAIL_ADDRESS,COMPLAINT_ID)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Comment: Some general comments on the code itself: 1) you should be using a database sequence to auto-increment the ID, not doing it in code; 2) When you catch an exception and print the stack trace you must rethrow it (or a `RuntimeException`) if you don't want the code to continue as if nothing happened.

Comment: @JimGarrison: A database sequence? Please enlighten, that would be a big help

Comment: Please use Google to look up "database sequence"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps just try calling executeUpdate() with no parameters. You've already set the query string when you created the PreparedStatement.

```
 ps.executeUpdate()
```

Comment: First of all really sorry that I can't upvote your answer(MY REP) ,secondly problem solved and that is unbelievable .I am really interested in why this didn't work with ps.executeUpdate(query)? Thirdly Can please anyone tell me what is a database sequence and how should I use it to autoincrement a variable in a database?

Comment: @pulp_fiction you can't upvote the answer but you can set it as the correct answer though.

Comment: @boolean : Yeah and I did it although a bit late!